# PostgreSQL - How to merge data from multiple rows using join from other tables

Tags: postgresql

I am using postgresql 9.6 and want to merge data from multiple rows into one. I'm using 4 tables(the table format and data cannot be changed)

Tables are-

```
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('product_a_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"name" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
"organization_id" int4,
"description" text COLLATE "default",
"image" varchar(255) COLLATE "default" DEFAULT 'https://abcd.com'::character varying,
"deleted" bool,
"price" float4,
"currency_id" int4,
CONSTRAINT "product_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)

CREATE TABLE "public"."product_asset" (
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('product_asset_a_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"product_id" int4,
"asset_type" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
"asset_url" text COLLATE "default",
"asset_value" text COLLATE "default",
"asset_name" text COLLATE "default",
CONSTRAINT "product_asset_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)

CREATE TABLE "public"."user" (
"id" int4 DEFAULT nextval('istar_user_a_seq'::regclass) NOT NULL,
"mobile" varchar COLLATE "default",
"name" varchar(255) COLLATE "default",
"organization_id" int4,
CONSTRAINT "istar_user_pkey" PRIMARY KEY ("id")
)

CREATE TABLE "public"."pipeline_product" (
"pipeline_id" int4 NOT NULL,
"product_id" int4 NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "uq_pipeline_product_pipeline_id_product_id" UNIQUE ("pipeline_id", "product_id")
)
```

For each product there can be multiple assets and pipelines

I want all data grouped according to product.id, here's my initial attempt

```
SELECT
    product. ID AS pid,
    product. NAME AS pname,
    product.price,
    product.currency_id,
    product.description,
    product_asset.asset_type,
    product_asset.asset_url,
    product_asset.asset_name,
    product_asset.asset_value,
    product_asset. ID AS asset_id,
    String_agg (  pipeline_product.pipeline_id :: TEXT, ',' ) AS process_id
FROM
    product
LEFT JOIN product_asset ON product_asset.product_id = product. ID
AND product_asset.is_active = TRUE
LEFT JOIN pipeline_product ON pipeline_product.product_id = product. ID
WHERE
    organization_id IN (
        SELECT
            "user" .organization_id
        FROM
            "user"
        WHERE
            "user" . ID = 218915
    )
AND deleted = FALSE
GROUP BY
    pid,
    product_asset. ID,
    product_asset.asset_type,
    product_asset.asset_name,
    product_asset.asset_url,
product_asset.asset_value
```

and i get output as:

[image: sql_op]

I need only one entry for the `product.id` and everything else should be in a single column,
I am using string_agg() function. What am I missing?

Comment: If only want one row per `product.id` then you should group **only** by that column.

Answer (score 0):

I see three issues in your query:

1. `product_asset.asset_url` is not unique, use `max(product_asset.asset_url)`
2. `product_asset.ID` is not unique, so you cannot group it. Use `min(product_asset.ID)` or `max(product_asset. ID)`
3. `String_agg(pipeline_product.pipeline_id :: TEXT, ',')` does not return always the same value, because they are not sorted, You should add `ORDER BY pipeline_product.product_id, pipeline_product.pipeline_id`.